# Django order_by query runs incredibly slow in Python, but fast in DB

Tags: python, django

I have the following models:

```
class Shelf(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, editable=False)
    games = models.ManyToManyField(Game, blank=True, through='SortedShelfGames')
    objects = ShelfManager()
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

class SortedShelfGames(models.Model):
    game = models.ForeignKey(Game, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    shelf = models.ForeignKey(Shelf, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField()
    order = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    releases = models.ManyToManyField(Release)
    objects = SortedShelfGamesManager.as_manager()

class Game(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300, db_index=True)
    sort_name = models.CharField(max_length=300, db_index=True)
    ...
```

I have a view where I want to get all of a user's SortedShelfGames, distinct on the Game relationship. I then want to be able to sort that list of SortedShelfGames on a few different fields. So right now, I'm doing the following inside of the SortedShelfGamesManager (which inherits from models.QuerySet) to get the list:

```
games = self.filter(
   pk__in=Subquery(
      self.filter(shelf__user=user).distinct('game').order_by('game', 'date_added').values('pk') # The order_by statement in here is to get the earliest date_added field for display
   )
)
```

That works the way it's supposed to. However, whenever I try and do an order_by('game__sort_name'), the query takes forever in my python. When I'm actually trying to use it on my site, it just times out. If I take the generated SQL and just run it on my database, it returns all of my results in a fraction of a second. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here. The SortedShelfGames table has millions of records in it if that matters.

This is the generated SQL:

```
SELECT 
    "collection_sortedshelfgames"."id", "collection_sortedshelfgames"."game_id", "collection_sortedshelfgames"."shelf_id", "collection_sortedshelfgames"."date_added", "collection_sortedshelfgames"."order", 
    (SELECT U0."rating" FROM "reviews_review" U0 WHERE (U0."game_id" = "collection_sortedshelfgames"."game_id" AND U0."user_id" = 1 AND U0."main") LIMIT 1) AS "score", 
    "games_game"."id", "games_game"."created", "games_game"."last_updated", "games_game"."exact", "games_game"."date", "games_game"."year", "games_game"."quarter", "games_game"."month", "games_game"."name", "games_game"."sort_name", "games_game"."rating_id", "games_game"."box_art", "games_game"."description", "games_game"."slug", "games_game"."giantbomb_id", "games_game"."ignore_giantbomb", "games_game"."ignore_front_page", "games_game"."approved", "games_game"."user_id", "games_game"."last_edited_by_id", "games_game"."dlc", "games_game"."parent_game_id" 
FROM 
    "collection_sortedshelfgames" 
INNER JOIN 
    "games_game" 
ON 
    ("collection_sortedshelfgames"."game_id" = "games_game"."id") 
WHERE 
    "collection_sortedshelfgames"."id" 
IN (
    SELECT 
        DISTINCT ON (U0."game_id") U0."id" 
    FROM 
        "collection_sortedshelfgames" U0 
    INNER JOIN 
        "collection_shelf" U1 ON (U0."shelf_id" = U1."id") 
    WHERE 
        U1."user_id" = 1 
    ORDER 
        BY U0."game_id" ASC, U0."date_added" ASC
) 
ORDER BY
    "games_game"."sort_name" ASC
```

Comment: Yes, the "millions of records" matters here alot (the double column ordering alone can make this very slow on big tables, if you have no combined index). Can you show the generated SQL? Did you run exactly the same SQL in the cmdline as django? On which database? Have you checked EXPLAIN and ANALYZE (on postgres)?

Comment: @jerch I've added the generated SQL. I literally copied and pasted that right into the PSQL command line and it spits out the 1388 records in the order I want it instantly. It's something weird going on in Django I think. I've run EXPLAIN on it, and it seems to be doing all index scans. I'm not the greatest at reading those though.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need a `Subquery` for this.

Comment: I believe you need a Subquery if you want to be able to order the results of a distinct query by something other than what you are doing the distinct "on." In this case, I'm doing a distinct on "game" (translates to "game.id") but I want to be able to order by the sort_name. You can't do that without a Subquery I don't think.

Comment: If the main query is just filtering on the primary keys, how/why does the order matter?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up doing to solve this. Instead of using a Subquery, I created a list of primary keys by evaluating what I was using as the Subquery in, then feeding that into my query. It looks like this:

```
pks = list(self.filter(shelf__user=user).distinct('game').values_list('pk', flat=True))
games = self.filter(
   pk__in=pks)
)
games = games.order_by('game__sort_name')
```

This ended up being pretty fast. This is essentially the same thing as the Subquery method, but whatever was going on underneath the hood in python/Django was slowing this way down.

Comment: you can club below lines :-
`games = self.filter(pk__in=pks).order_by('game__sort_name')`

Comment: Hmm, yes sometimes extracting the pks of interest beforehand will help, but note that the WHERE IN clause might lead to a new bottleneck, if the pk list is rather big (postgres creates a temporary bitmap for those). The main issue I have with your issue is that you say, that it runs fine in psql, but not in Django. If you care enough - could you try to run old SQL query on a naked cursor in python? (accessible with `from django.db import connection` then `with connection.cursor() as c: c.execute(...)`)

Comment: Imho the fastest solution to your filter idea would be a self join on a group by aggregation of a subselect. But thats almost impossible to express in plain django ORM syntax (raw queries are your friend).

Comment: @jerch I ran the raw query using the cursor method in the shell on the live server. It ran very fast. The PK solution seems to be working well enough. The biggest the PK list could ever be is around 5000, and it runs fast when the list is that big. I have no idea what extra joining or querying is going on under the hood. I appreciate all the help. You've given me a couple ideas to try I hadn't thought of.